# Why the StopTimer() method causes the app to crash when invoked after the app is cleared from recent tasks?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, countdowntimer

I am trying to create an app that would listen to wifi state changes and run a countdown timer in a service in between the changes. If I enable wifi while the activity is in foreground and then disabling wifi after clearing the recent tasks causes the app to crash. After the crash it is throwing a null pointer exception at a method which is responsible for stopping the countdown timer. But If I do both enabling and disabling after I have cleared the recent tasks the app wouldn't crash.

This is the code from BroadcastReciever's OnReceive method which is responsible for handling the WIFI_STATE_DISABLED state:

```
case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
                    count++;
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("Count", count).apply();
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Integer.toString(count), "Disabled at -" + simpleDateFormat.format(new Date())).apply();

                    if (activityRunning) {
                        arrayList.add("Disabled at " + simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        textView.setText("Disabled");
                        aSwitch.setChecked(false);
                    }

                    if (context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.wifilimiter",MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("timerRunning", false)) {
                        stopTimer(context);    
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putLong("millisLeft", millisleft).apply();
                    }
                    break;
```

This the above mentioned StopTimer method:

```
    public static void stopTimer(Context context) {
        if (context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.wifilimiter",MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("timerRunning", false)) {
            countDownTimer.cancel(); // The app crushes here
            context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.wifilimiter",MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("timerRunning",false).apply();
            Log.d("Timer Running : ","false");
        }
```

This the CountDownTimer :

```
public static void startTimer(final Context context) {
        context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.wifilimiter",MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("timerRunning", true).apply();
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisleft, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                millisleft = millisUntilFinished;
                String hms = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisleft),
                        MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisleft) - HOURS.toMinutes(MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisleft)),
                        MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisleft) - MINUTES.toSeconds(MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisleft)));

                Toast.makeText(context, hms, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.wifilimiter",MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("activityStatus",false)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTick: " + hms);
                    timer.setText(hms);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

This is the log below:

```
    Process: com.example.wifilimiter, PID: 5306
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.wifilimiter.BroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2424)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.wifilimiter.TimerService.stopTimer(TimerService.java:67) //This refers to the countDownTimer.cancel() method
        at com.example.wifilimiter.BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(BroadcastReceiver.java:85)//This refers to the StopTimer() method
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2417)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Be sure you are calling startTimer. If not so it is normal getting NullPointerException at stopTimer.

Comment: You assume your app is not being terminated & restarted in-between `startTimer()` and `stopTimer()`. This is probably incorrect. The app/service is being terminated, and `stopTimer()` is being called in a new app instance that has never experienced a `startTimer()`, therefor `countDownTimer` is null.

Comment: so what can I do to ensure that my service doesn't get interrupted?

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the app from the list of recent tasks, the OS process hosting the app is killed. Your timer is now dead.

You need to check if your timer is running in `onReceive()` by checking if `countDownTimer` is `null`. If it is, your timer isn't running and you no longer need to stop it.

Comment: I have put my timer in a service class. Then why it would be dead when the app is killed ?

Comment: When a user removes a task from the recent tasks list, this usually results in the OS process hosting the app being killed. If you have a `Service` that has returned `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`, Android will restart that `Service`, but you probably aren't restarting your timer in that case. You should add the relevant code from your `Service` to the question so we can have a look. Please edit your question and copy the relevant code into the question, don't add the code as a comment.